# Set Statusbar Orientation is not working in iOS 6 in iPad2

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, orientation

I have found many answers related to my issue but no one can help me to solve my issue.

As my title says that statusbar orientation is not changing in iOS 6. I write proper code for change statusbar orientation but it's not working for me. its not work on both iOS Simulator & Device (iPad).

in my rootviewcontroller, i have implemented same as bellow code, with UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll, after that, i used presentModelViewController to bring child view controller, but in child view controller i am not able to change statusbar orientation.

i also implemented

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

in AppDelegate.

**My Code is :**

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];

}
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: You are setting the status bar orientation to portrait in app delegate and in root view setting the view to mask all. It is not necessary to apply that in app delegate if you are using he method in root view. Have you tried commenting out the orientation method in app delegate and see if the status bar changes orientation with method applied in root view only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to answer `NO` to the shouldrotate method in your rootViewController to it works.

Take a look at the documentation

> Discussion The value of this property is a constant that indicates an
>   orientation of the receiver's status bar. See UIInterfaceOrientation
>   for details. Setting this property rotates the status bar to the
>   specified orientation without animating the transition. If your
>   application has rotatable window content, however, you should not
>   arbitrarily set status-bar orientation using this method. **The
>   status-bar orientation set by this method does not change if the
>   device changes orientation.** For more on rotatable window views, see
>   View Controller Programming Guide for iOS.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/statusBarOrientation

Comment: Hey dude ...really thank you so much...:) i solved my issue from you code.